# Python: data filtration based on sorted result

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe with sample data like so;

```
ID,CLASS,CLASS_ID,EXPIRY,VOLUME
1,012345,12,70,100
2,987654,99,10,800
3,012345,11,70,200
4,012345,10,60,700
5,987654,24,20,300
6,012345,06,70,900
7,987654,08,60,500
```

The agenda is to select those distinct records having the greatest `EXPIRY`. In case of `987654` that would be

```
7,987654,08,60,500
```

This I can easily accomplished by,

```
df.sort_values(['CLASS','EXPIRY'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CLASS'], inplace=True)
```

But in case of `012345` has multiple record with same expiry of `70`. So in this case(i.e., after sorting based on `CLASS` & `EXPIRY`, **if and only if** multiple records with highest valued `EXPIRY` are found), I have to select that record which is having the greatest `VOLUME` among the **records** having greatest `EXPIRY`. Herein lies my problem.

Expected Output:

```
ID,CLASS,CLASS_ID,EXPIRY,VOLUME
7,987654,08,60,500
6,012345,6,70,900    #this record has greatest `VOLUME` among the records having common `EXPIRY`
```

Can somebody help with doing it in a pythonic way?

Comment: In your example there are no common elements with `EXPIRY`. Seems like you only need to add `f.sort_values(['CLASS','EXPIRY','VOLUME']`

Comment: @yatu: Apologies for that. please check the data now

Comment: As mentioned, you only need to add `VOLUME` when calling `sort_values`, 
`df.sort_values(['CLASS','EXPIRY','VOLUME'], inplace=True, ascending=False)

`

Comment: You're correct. kinldy put it up as an answer and ill mark it right